# Does Kusto not support regex lookarounds?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, azure-data-explorer, kql

It seems that Kusto doesn't support regex lookarounds, as I get the following errors when I try to run the below commands. Am I using the wrong syntax? If this feature really isn't supported, where can I give feedback to vote for this feature?

---

**Positive Lookahead Test:**

```
print(extract("t(?=t)", 0, "http"))
```

> **Expected Output:** `tt`
>
> **Actual Error:** `Relop semantic error: 'extract()' has the following semantic error: SEM0420: Regex pattern is ill-formed: t(?=t).`

---

**Negative Lookahead Test:**

```
print(extract("t(?!t)", 0, "http"))
```

> **Expected Output:** `tp`
>
> **Actual Error:** `Relop semantic error: 'extract()' has the following semantic error: SEM0420: Regex pattern is ill-formed: t(?!t).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kusto uses the `re2` library: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax, as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/re2

What you're trying to achieve isn't supported by that library - see https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2:

> As a matter of principle, RE2 does not support constructs for which only backtracking solutions are known to exist. Thus, backreferences and look-around assertions are not supported.

As for your other question, feature requests can be submitted/upvoted @ https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice