# Regex to match SHA1 but must contain HEX characters

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql, re2

I have this regex to find SHA1's in a Kusto column:

```
\b[a-fA-F0-9]{40}\b
```

However, I am getting lots of matches for non-hex numbers (only 1-9 digits). How can I ensure that the match contains at least one HEX digit (a-f)?

Kusto doesn't support lookarounds according to this: [Does Kusto not support regex lookarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998863/does-kusto-not-support-regex-lookarounds)

Comment: Put: `(?=.*[a-fA-F])`in front.

Comment: `I am getting lots of matches for non-hex numbers (only 1-9 digits).` How do you know they are not hex though? A Hexadecimal number doesn't necessarily have to contain a letter.

Comment: Actually this: `(?<!\d{40})` AFTER it might be better.

Comment: While my regex might answer what you ask, the problem is that hex numbers CAN be all numbers, which will fail. You need to look at what surrounds those sha characters.

Comment: I was trying to use lookarounds to accomplish this and just realized that they are not supported by Kusto. I just edited the question to make it clear that I am working with Kusto. Is there another way?

Also, I agree that a HEX number can contain only decimal digits, but it's unlikely that a 40 digits long HEX number doesn't contain A-F at some point. Since I am getting a lot of non-relevant matches, I prefer to take the low risk of missing a SHA1 that only contains decimals

Comment: Another option I have is to use extract_all and then mv-expand and then filter out the matches that only contain decimal digits, but when I do this my query runs out of memory because there are many matches. I need to filter directly from the regex without using lookarounds.

Comment: Seems very strange. You get a lot of matches for numbers with exactly 40 digits?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can match 40 digits between word boundaries to get that out of the way, and use an alternation `|` with a capture group `([a-fA-F0-9]{40})` to capture what you would allow with *extract_all*

```
\b[0-9]{40}\b|\b([a-fA-F0-9]{40})\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/54TDKL/1) with the capture group value.

Comment: This works perfectly when I do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73312148/5165989) where I check if the column matches the pattern `where Content matches regex '\b[a-fA-F0-9]{40}\b'` and then use _extract_all_ with the pattern you suggest. If I remove the first filter, I get many more results with an empty _match_ column (from 66K records to memory budget exceeded error on 190K records). I still think this is the best answer, just wondering why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use [extract_all(),](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractallfunction) & [array_length()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraylengthfunction) to check the number of Hex strings Vs. the number of Dec strings.

Please note that with this method we don't really need to extract anything but empty strings.

```
datatable(text:string)
[
    "SHA1: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743 e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02"
   ,"Only digits: 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743"
   ,"Too short: f0cf934569319b10e85a9d"
   ,"Too long: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c123"
   ,"888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399"
]
| where array_length(extract_all(@"\b[[:xdigit:]]{40}\b()", text)) > coalesce(array_length(extract_all(@"\b\d{40}\b()", text)), 0)
```

| text |
| --- |
| SHA1: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743 e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02 |
| 888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA41RS0vDQBC+F/oflpwS6GF39pGdHERv3jzorS1lso+ksCSQLNii/ndjRREU6XyHuXyP+RhPeUGbQpnDKTdzno5DV61X2/WKLVM83t+JhkEtvYweIncRpdIGpcBW8GA1oY/kXYxCSMdMjYILMBpBSG0sKKMtCMWl4mhrJfXnYkGjA8TWLTZWgOJOK7OAUJIDrzznwgUOxeWOTfEwpDPzx+6Y5+bqlC/x0ziyuR+n3LC/G/wkpnHorm8s4DvFWhvIL7lUO20gRGEUBCudI64jRAROIBEX/n69emXPfZgCo2mi8yGFoct9ubxgIpcPlFJ5W+za7bY5XUo3+/2L4m+7tqyKDft4VVWxG+ZGSmF2ofzXZed/aTeMV+/5wRLI+wEAAA==)

---

By leveraging [set_difference()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/setdifferencefunction) we can get the SHA1 values

```
datatable(text:string)
[
    "SHA1: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743 e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02"
   ,"Only digits: 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743"
   ,"Too short: f0cf934569319b10e85a9d"
   ,"Too long: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c123"
   ,"888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399"
]
| extend hex = extract_all(@"\b([[:xdigit:]]{40})\b", text), dec = extract_all(@"\b(\d{40})\b", text)
| extend sha1 = set_difference(hex, dec)
```

| text | hex | dec | sha1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SHA1: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743 e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02 | ["273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c","6791012659213568246582140340987435098743","e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02"] | ["6791012659213568246582140340987435098743"] | ["273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c","e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02"] |
| Only digits: 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743 | ["6791012659213568246582140340987435098743"] | ["6791012659213568246582140340987435098743"] | [] |
| Too short: f0cf934569319b10e85a9d |  |  |  |
| Too long: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c123 |  |  |  |
| 888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399 | ["888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399"] |  | ["888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42RP2vDMBDF90C+g/BkQwbp9Mc6Q6HdunVotyQEWTo5BmODrSGl7XevktISSoboBiF47356d8GlXO1AZaJTapY092NXrVfb9YrlU7w+P4mGQS2DjAEi9xGl0galwFZwstphiC74GIWQnpkaBRdgNIKQ2lhQRlsQikvF0dZK6p+LkUYPiK3PbawAxb1WJpdD6TwEFTgXnjgUl39sipdxeGeh7/q0NHdTfs1v08SW4zSnht1OcC0cprG7P7GAP4q1llzIXFd7bYCiMArISu8d1xEiAncgEbN+v159sjxvGgM70ok9nB+z8+nghqF8LHZtud02p0veZr//UPyr2rXFhp2XVG1YIH/Lswv/lFeY5ehE9iyUDqGPkWYaPZUZfulWfQP43DyjCAIAAA==)

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on [extract_all()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractallfunction) followed by [matches regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/regex-operator) on the results.

Extract all 40 length Hex strings and check if the result contains a character of the set `[a-fA-F]`

```
datatable(text:string)
[
    "SHA1: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743 e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02"
   ,"Only digits: 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743"
   ,"Too short: f0cf934569319b10e85a9d"
   ,"Too long: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c123"
   ,"888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399"
]
| where extract_all(@"\b([[:xdigit:]]{40})\b", text) matches regex "[a-fA-F]"
```

| text |
| --- |
| SHA1: 273d3fd2f0cf934569319b10e85a9dfadcff113c 6791012659213568246582140340987435098743 e59c299bc9b181240c546464a93ac2d4d001ce02 |
| 888ead874a7c562ef1642e83cca05f2f920a2399 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA41Ru27DMAzc/RWCphhIAIl6WPTULEW3Du3mGIUsUU4ANwZsAXXR9t/r9AF06BDewOXIuyOjzyu6gTaZllzPeTqd%207JoCrYWf7jby5pBpaJKEZIICZU2FpXETgpyxmNMPoaUpFSB2QqlkGANglTGOtDWOJBaKC3QVVqZ78bIYADELqxrnAQtgtF2hUflA0QdhZCBBPCLjS2/Pw%20vLJ76U57rq0V%20Zh/Hkc3Hcco1%209//H94wnvvr40r41XDOkY%20rqK%20CsUBJWg3kVAhemAQJQXhQiLxoi3f2cqSJ2HrtyYf85Idhc8MP3aZp6uUrY922b1p8lIeOb9nlKyV79jkcaWYT9bQw3vhd2u9uW/4JDmNRQb4BAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

I made my query more efficient and was able to resolve later in the Kusto query instead of changing the regex. I will not mark this as an answer because the original question is about how to accomplish this from the regex itself and it would be interesting to have that answer.

This is what I did:

```
...
| where Content matches regex @'\b[a-fA-F0-9]{40}\b'
| extend match = extract_all(@'(\b[a-fA-F0-9]{40}\b)', Content) 
| mv-expand match
| where not (match matches regex @'\b[0-9]{40}\b')
...
```

In the last line I remove matches with all decimal digits